# Javascript return after XMLHTTPRequest()

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I have this problem, so I want to return the value received after an XMLHTTPRequest(), is this possible? If not, how would I go about achieving the same general idea? Here's what I have so far (It is obviously not working).

```
function something(url) {
     var temp = getPage(url);
     console.log(temp);
}

function getPage(url) {
     var x = new XMLHTTPRequest();
     x.onload = function() {
          var html = x.responseText;
          //CODE TO PARSE HTML TEXT
          var variable = SOMETHING PARSED FROM HTML
          return variable;
     }
     x.open("GET", url);
     x.send();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the programming paradigm that every new javascript developer has to deal with.

Because of the asynchronous nature of javascript, functions tend not to pass values back via `return` statements, but instead the values are passed back via callback methods.

```
function something(url) {
     getPage(url, function(temp) {
         console.log(temp);
     });
}

function getPage(url, callback) {
     var x = new XMLHTTPRequest();
     x.onload = function() {
          var html = x.responseText;
          //CODE TO PARSE HTML TEXT
          var variable = SOMETHING PARSED FROM HTML
          callback(variable);
     }
     x.open("GET", url);
     x.send();
}
```

Comment: If I need multiple call backs like multiple functions that use XMLHTTPRequest after one another, would I just do the same "callback" for each function?

Comment: for example... somefunction(url, function(res) { callback(res); });